# why only adding last element arraylist on new arraylist

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, duplicates, element

there's the goal result :
[[a],[a,b],[a,b,c]]

but when I running my code, the result was :
[[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c]]

this is the source code :

```
public class Try {


    ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<List<String>> hm=new ArrayList<List<String>>();


    public void addal2(){
        for(int j=0; j<3;j++){
            al.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<1;i++){
                if(j==0){al.add("a");}
                else if(j==1){al.add("a");al.add("b");}
                else if(j==2){al.add("a");al.add("b");al.add("c");}
            }
            hm.add(al);
        }
        System.out.println("hm final"+hm);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Try c = new Try();
        c.addal2();
    }

}
```

Please tell me why the result is such HM just adding last element?

Comment: please be more specific in your question, stackOverflow is not meant as a place to post a half-assed homework attempt and get us to fix it.

Comment: You're adding the same list three times and altering its content. Instead of clearing it at the start of your loop, make a new list.

Comment: @khelwood I thought I can get every single Arraylist al in every loop of j and adding once by once to List hm, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element is not being added to HM, you're adding a reference to the same list to HM.

Iteration 1: HM = ["a"]

Iteration 2: HM = [["a", "b"], ["a","b"]]

Iteration 3: HM = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]

This is easily fix by instead of clearing the list, just re-instantiate it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<List<String>> hm = new ArrayList();

    for(int j=0; j<3;j++){
        List<String> al = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i<1;i++){
            if(j==0){al.add("a");}
            else if(j==1){al.add("a");al.add("b");}
            else if(j==2){al.add("a");al.add("b");al.add("c");}
        }
        hm.add(al);
    }
    System.out.println("hm final"+hm);
}
```

Results:

> hm final[[a], [a, b], [a, b, c]]

### UPDATE

As far as cleaning up your code to make it simpler, you can try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<List<String>> hm = new ArrayList();
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    // Change the 3 to any number from 1 - 26
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        List<String> al = new ArrayList();
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            al.add(String.valueOf(alphabet.charAt(j)));
        }
        hm.add(al);
    }
    System.out.println(hm);
}
```

Results:

> [[a], [a, b], [a, b, c]]

Answer (score -1):

I find that your code cannot really be repaired, I'd do it like something this:

```
public class Main {
  private static List<List<String>> addal2(final String... abc) {
    final List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final String x : abc) {
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(Arrays.asList(x));
            continue;
        }
        final List<String> lastList = result.get(result.size() - 1);
        final List<String> newLastList = new ArrayList<>();
        newLastList.addAll(lastList);
        newLastList.add(x);
        result.add(newLastList);
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<List<String>> result = addal2("a", "b", "c");
    System.out.println(result); // Prints "[[a], [a, b], [a, b, c]]"
  }
}
```